# Peroblema con httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase

Tags: java, android

Hol,a estoy creando un app android  pero tengo un error que me tiene descpncertado ya que nunca me habīa pasado esto antes.

```
    public void UpdateState(final String iddispositivo, final String iduser, final String uubicacion) {
        class UpDni extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "Accediendo", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {
              super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("correcto")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proceso exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proceso Incorrecto ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, httpResponseMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                hashMap.put("iddispositivo", params[0]);
                hashMap.put("iduser", params[1]);
                hashMap.put("ubicacion", params[2]);
                finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, updatee);
                return finalResult;
            }
        }
        UpDni UPD = new UpDni();
        UPD.execute(iddispositivo, iduser, uubicacion);
    }
```

Resulta que siempre en el if me arroja proceso incorrecto y despues muestra el mensaje "correcto" osea que si esta repondiendo de manera adecuada el servidor, al principio creīa que era un problema del servidor y decidi probar de la siguiente forma en el .php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
////////////////si no se cumple if (($calendarioid != '') && ($usubloq == '0'))
$incidenciaid = $_POST['iddispositivo
']
$usuarioid = $_POST['iduser'];
$ubicacion = $_POST['ubicacion'];
 echo "correcto";
}
```

Osea en teoría siempre debería mostrarme proceso exitoso pero me muestra proceso incorrecto e imprime  "correcto" osea que si esta recibiendo de forma adecuada .

Comment: probaste haciendo un trim de httpResponseMsg para ver si tiene algun espacio?

Comment: puede ser que te salte el timeout de la petición y la respuesta te llegue después? Sería una explicación de porque primero te da error y luego correcta.

Comment: Muestra en el Toast el valor de httpResponseMsg, mediante: Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proceso Incorrecto!, mensaje: " + httpResponseMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te podría asegurar que la respuesta en realidad no retorna "correcto" o lo retorna con espacios u otros caracteres, para comprobar esto agrega el `String` de la respuesta en el caso de no encontrar la palabra "correcto", te sugiero además usar el método `trim()` para eliminar espacios en los extremos:

```
  if (httpResponseMsg.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("correcto")) {
```

Ejemplo:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {
      super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (httpResponseMsg.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("correcto")) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proceso exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proceso Incorrecto!, mensaje: " + httpResponseMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```